# reason behind spring.json.trusted.packages

Tags: spring-kafka

Can someone please explain the design decision behind the "spring.json.trusted.packages" for spring-kafka deserializer?

I have no issues in Serializing and deserialing some DTOs in spring mvc. I do not have to add this. but why does spring-kafka need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because currently `JsonDeserializer` in spring-kafka supports deserialising the receiving data to a particular java type that is specified by the `__TypeId__` message header.

And it is known that Java deserialisation has vulnerability that can cause code execution (see [this](https://snyk.io/blog/serialization-and-deserialization-in-java/) for details) and if your classpath somehow contains some malicious classes , an attacker can send a message which configure the `__TypeId__` header to be a malicious class and execute some codes. So `spring.json.trusted.packages` is used to alleviate this problem which only allow classess under the trusted package to be deserialized into.

In spring-mvc , normally you will not design an API endpoint which the request body allows users to configure which java class it will deserialise into. That 's why you cannot found such configuration in the spring-mvc. But if you have such API endpoint , it also has this vulnerability which is mentioned at [here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4544).

Comment: Good info. Thanks.